# Ansible, dynamically create list of dictionaries from pattern match of variable names

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to dynamically create a list of dictionaries in Ansible, from exiting variables which are named in a similar manner. I can't really modify the existing variables, as they are used by other things in the project.

Assuming the following variables exists already:

```
item_1a:
  name: first test item
  value: 100

item_2a: 
  name: second test item
  value: 200
  options: extra

item_zz:
  name: last test item
  option: nameless
```

What I need to create dynamically from all variables with name matching `^item_*`:

```
dynamic_list:
  - name: first test item
    value: 100
  - name: second test item
    value: 200
    options: extra
  - name: last test item
    option: nameless
```

Can I query vars by name pattern, in any manner?

Comment: Are you aware of `vars.keys()` and `hostvars["whatever-host"].keys()`?

Comment: @mdaniel, yes, you can also get a list of keys from varnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, the task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dynamic_list: "{{ my_vars|map('extract', vars)|list }}"
      vars:
        my_vars: "{{ vars|select('match', '^item_.*$')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  dynamic_list:
  - name: first test item
    value: 100
  - name: second test item
    options: extra
    value: 200
  - name: last test item
    option: nameless
```

Comment: Can you explain why the set_fact is necessary?  Also, anyway to not set every variable as a fact at least?

Comment: *set_fact* is not needed. Put it where you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting the list in the following way,

```yaml
  vars:
    varname_list: "{{ query(varnames, '^item_.*$') }}"
    dynamic_list: "{{ varname_list | map('extract', vars) | list }}"
```